# Defining new methods to a const object in JS

Tags: javascript

I'm familiar with standard OOP in various languages so I don't consider myself to be of the faint of heart and if I were to see a standard class definition with class functions, etc. wouldn't bat an eye, but recently I stumbled upon another weird pattern I was unfamiliar with that rocked my world sort of speaking:

```
const obj1 = {}; 
obj1.myNewMethod = (param1, param2) => {
    // do something with param1 and/or 2
    return something;
}
```

It literally took me half an hour staring at a bunch of code similar to this above to realize it's not calling anonymous functions, nor is it assigning values to the object property, nor anything else I'd ever seen before. Now here's the issue - since I've no clue what this definition pattern is called, I can't RTFM and learn more about it - like for instance how to define async extension methods. My kneejerk reaction would be to do `obj1.method = async (args) => {}` and through testing I confirmed it is correct, but I don't wanna bruteforce every single possible programming pattern to see which one is toi be used how.

So any pointers to the name of this "technique", "pattern" or whatever you wanna call it?

Comment: You're just assigning a function to an object property, which makes it a "method" in OOP terms. You can add arbitrary properties to virtually any object at any time, and functions are simply one of the possible values you can assign to properties. That's all.

Comment: So it's not some new ECMA standard or whatever. Great, that answers my question. Cheers!

Comment: While you can use arrow functions for this purpose, I'd recommend using a normal function (possibly with `.bind(obj1)`) so that you can access `this` inside the method. Otherwise it's really just a loose function not a method.

Comment: "nor is it assigning values to the object property" — It is. The property name is `myNewMethod`, the value is a function.